# Codeignitor Pagination with specific limited data random

Tags: codeigniter

I have a pathetic problem. I can't able to cope with this situation. please help.
I want to retrieve random limited data from a large number of data specified by category.
Normally I am able to retrieve that data from below code.
But problem happened when I tried those data for pagination.

Though I first limited  [$this->db->limit(6)] so in pagination coding I can't able to use [($limit, $start)] parameter.

Another problem is when I go next page then randomly new data come.

My points below:
1. how to fix limit problem.
2. if I change the page then new data(randomly) come.
that means every time data change.
3. I want retrieve data one time from database then paginate those data until I reload the page.
I want to use ajax but can't able.

```
May also share if any tutorial or example.
```

Below Code:

```
//below is controller code:

public function post_data()
    {
        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['total_rows'] = $this->post_model->post_rows();//specific limited rows will retrieve
        $config['per_page'] = 6;
        $config['num_links'] = 2;
        $config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'page-link' );

        if ($this->input->get('page')) {
            $sgm = (int) trim($this->input->get('page'));
            $start = $config['per_page'] * ($sgm - 1);
        } else {
            $start = 0;
        }

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['post_data'] = $this->post_model->post($config['per_page'], $start);

        $data['main_content'] = 'post_view';
        $this->load->view('include/template', $data);
    }

//below is model code:

// to count row for pagination
    public function post_rows()
    {
        $this->db->select('id , post_title, post_desc, aut_name, date');
        $this->db->from('tbl_post');
        $this->db->where_in('cat_id', 1);
        $this->db->order_by('cat_id' , 'RANDOM');
        $this->db->limit(6);//limit can be change  
        $query1 = $this->db->get();
        $query1 = $query1->num_rows();

        $this->db->select('id , post_title, post_desc, aut_name, date');
        $this->db->from('tbl_post');
        $this->db->where_in('cat_id', 1);
        $this->db->order_by('cat_id' , 'RANDOM');
        $this->db->limit(6);//limit can be change  
        $query2 = $this->db->get();
        $query2 = $query2->num_rows();

        $query = $query1 + $query2;

        return $query;
    }

    public function post($limit, $start)
    {
        $this->db->select('id , post_title, post_desc, aut_name, date');
        $this->db->from('tbl_post');
        $this->db->where_in('cat_id', 1);
        $this->db->order_by('cat_id' , 'RANDOM');
        $this->db->limit(6);
        $query1 = $this->db->get();
        $query1 = $query1->result_array();

        $this->db->select('id , post_title, post_desc, aut_name, date');
        $this->db->from('tbl_post');
        $this->db->where_in('cat_id', 1);
        $this->db->order_by('cat_id' , 'RANDOM');
        $this->db->limit(6); 
        $query2 = $this->db->get();
        $query2 = $query2->result_array();

        //My question is : here how can I use $limit & $start ?

        $query = array_merge($array1 , $array2);

        return $query;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use order by rand(), you need to generate view from your random queries, and then use the view data to create the pagination
(which not applicable if you have large users and dataset).

You can create a random seeds (can be saved in session), create additional fields by using hash algorithm (md5, sha256, etc) with your primary key (or another unique fields), and sort the field using your seed field.
And everytime you want to re-shuffle your list, you can reset your random seed (in which case you can change the seed everytime your page get refreshed).

```
//save seed in session
$seed = rand(0,99999);

$this->db->select('id , post_title, post_desc, aut_name, date, md5(id+seed) as seeds');
$this->db->from('tbl_post');
$this->db->where_in('cat_id', 1);
$this->db->order_by('seeds');
$this->db->limit($start,$limit);
```